# Web scraping- how to find a path associated with non HTML element

Tags: python, web-scraping

The page below has a 'download data' button but this seems to be in a data visualization app. I wanted to be able to 'point' to this element but because it seems to be embedded in their, possibly proprietary, visualization software, I couldn't find something as standard as an XPath. Is there a way around this?

I have tried going through 'inspect' on chrome but it seems to be drawing a blank for me.

https://public.tableau.com/profile/public.health.wales.health.protection#!/vizhome/RapidCOVID-19virology-Public/Headlinesummary

Answer (score 0):

I've made [this tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping), you can get the dashboard this way :

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/RapidCOVID-19virology-Public/Headlinesummary"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getDashboard()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    #show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    #show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/64635354)

Output :

```
WORKSHEET NAME : Metadata
          Date-alias
0  31 Oct 2020 13:00
WORKSHEET NAME : Metadata dashboard updated
         Date-alias
0  1 Nov 2020 14:00
WORKSHEET NAME : Metadata deaths
          Date-value         Date-alias
0  31 Oct 2020 13:00  31 Oct 2020 13:00
WORKSHEET NAME : headline_numbers
                                            F1-value                                           F1-alias SUM(F2)-alias
0                       of which were newly reported                       of which were newly reported            16
1  Cumulative number of suspected COVID-19 deaths...  Cumulative number of suspected COVID-19 deaths...          1888
2                          Number of tests yesterday                          Number of tests yesterday          7280
3             Cumulative number of tests carried out             Cumulative number of tests carried out       1164296
4                      Cumulative individuals tested                      Cumulative individuals tested        745893
5    Cumulative individuals who were tested negative    Cumulative individuals who were tested negative        694202
6                    of which were new reports today                    of which were new reports today           819
7           Cumulative confirmed COVID-19 case total           Cumulative confirmed COVID-19 case total         51691
```